# Updating To Heroku Toolbelt v4 gets Access Denied Error

Tags: heroku, command-line, heroku-toolbelt

Annoying out of nowhere my Heroku toolbelt always attempts to update anytime I make a Heroku command. This wouldn't be so bad if it actually did update but no matter what permissions I give to the desination folder or CMD I get an `Access is Denied` error.

This makes executing commands on with Heroku extremely time consuming because it always re-downloads the update and fail in setting up Node before executing the command I ask it to.

Below is an example of what the error looks like.

```
Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... done.
For more information on Toolbelt v4: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli
Setting up node-v4.1.1... ▸    rename C:\Users\Anthony\.heroku\tmp\download110460667\file C:\Users\Anthony\.heroku\node-v4.1.1-windows-x86\bin\node.exe: Access is denied.
error loading plugin commands
error loading plugin topics
error loading plugin commands
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I just encounter this issue.

Comment: Just wait long enough and it will resolve on it's own. At least mine did. I still don't feel this is a real solution so I don't know what to telly you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting the folders Username/.heroku , and  Username/AppData/Local/heroku, (Replace "Username" with your username) then run heroku login results in a successful install of node, after that it seems to work smoothly (so far). Probably deleting the first folder isn't necessary -- but that's what I did in any case.

Good luck

PS:
Running on Windows 8

Comment: Thanks a ton..you are a live saver!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, on Windows 7 64Bit. 
Got it to work somehow...

Deleting the folders and running heroku again did not work for me, nor did renaming/removing the node.exe file.
Uninstalling pre-existing node.js installation and cleaning up PATH also did not help.
In the end I **edited the heroku.bat, setting a minimal PATH** with nothing but the ruby, heroku and git parts, i.e.

```
@SET PATH=%HEROKU_RUBY%;%HerokuPath%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
```

The node post-install went ok and I could login and clone an app with my pre-existing git installation. 
It even kept working after I reverted the batch file to the original PATH spec.

I have no clue why it didn't work with my orignal PATH, as there are no anomalies like & ampersands in it and no old ruby or node.js installs.
But now it works and I'm a happy camper :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can just rename or remove the node.exe application, and run heroku again.

Comment: Renaming or removing the node.exe didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the folder 'Username/AppData/Local/heroku' and try again

Answer (score 0):

uninstall heroku 3.x delete C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku folder and reinstall the latest https://toolbelt.heroku.com/ works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can unhide AppData folder in properties (right click on the folder and choose properties) -> tab: general -> Attributes: deselect the hide option. 
Run "heroku create" in terminal. Should work :)